# как создать ссылку на админку в джанго?

Tags: django, ссылки, админка

Обычно чтобы создать ссылку надо описать модель в views.py и прописать путь в urls.py, чтобы получилось как-то так
href="{% url 'articles:index' %} 
но как создать ссылку на админку(использую стандартную)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ваш шаблон:***

```py
{% url 'admin:index' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls,)
```

это ссылка для url